# Disable Plugin add-on for dataTable-reordering

Tags: jquery-ui, datatables

To disable dataTable plugin I can do this.

```
$('.dataTable').dataTable().fnDestry();
```

But how to disable the Reordering addon to the plugin?

This is how I initialized it on page load

```
$('.dataTable').dataTable().rowReordering();
```

Answer (score 2):

I've taken a look atthe code and i didn't find a way to disable it, maybe you could try destroing and recrating the table.

```
$('.dataTable').dataTable().fnDestry();
$('.dataTable').dataTable();
```

EDIT - if you set too many parameters, save them

```
var options = { .... };

$('.dataTable').dataTable(options);
```

Comment: I thought of doing that too, But am setting too many parameters on creation of dataTable.: (. I do not like losing the capability of double clicking on the columns in dataTables

Comment: @rudy but can't you save those parameters in an object and re-initialize the table with the same object?The other solution is changing the code of the plugin, i'm afraid